# Convert a large project using bitfields to use something more portable

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

I'm working on a large software project (a few million lines of code) that has been cobbled together for more than 20 years.  It's a mixture of Fortran/C/C++, currently targeted at Solaris & built with Sun Studio (though I have it compileable on clang/gcc).

We're moving the project to a Linux/x86 environment.  One of the challenges we're facing is a few thousand bitfields spread liberally across the project.

The current thinking is to do, more or less, something along these lines:

1) Whether manually (ouch) or through some sort of refactoring tool (perhaps made with clang), change all the bitfield definitions to reverse the order of bitfield members; e.g.:

```
 struct SomeStruct {
 #if defined( BIG_ENDIAN )
   int x1 : size1;
   int x2 : size2;
   /* ... */
 #else
   /* ... */
   int x2 : size2;
   int x1 : size1;
 #endif
 };
```

2) Any point at which we send/receive these bitfields we'd have to fix the byte order.

On the surface this seems like a passable (albeit not entirely portable) hack, but I'm very leery of it:

- It's error prone (oops, forgot to fix byte order; oops, updated the Solaris side of that struct but not the Linux side)
- Although Sun Studio & gcc appear to pack structs/bitfields the same way (when tested on the same platform) in the cases tested thus far, I won't be the least bit surprised to find there's corner cases, and knowing this code base it'll just so happen we have code using that corner case.
- Historically developers have been allowed to get away with anything they want (e.g., when we started running static analysis tools we found lots of code casting away const and a variety of other badness).  If there are /any/ corner cases involved here, some of the more questionable (existing) code may become even more brittle.

If we're already going to have to touch that much code to facilitate this move, my gut says we should just invest time in replacing them with something more portable that can serialize/deserialize itself so the bit/byte order is something dictated through the API as opposed to being a function of language/compiler nuances.

My question is: is the solution that stays with bitfields reasonable?  Are there any better solutions?  (keeping in mind that this could easily touch 30,000 lines of code or more)

Comment: You might look into [this](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safelabels.html); it claims to offer a much safer bitfield implementation. I don't know about byte order, though.

Comment: Looks like the system is serializing in an ad-hoc, platform-dependent way. Methinks future maintainability would be greatly improved by actually defining and documenting the serialization format, and handling byte-order conversion in the serialization code only. How the data is layed out in memory should be no concern. Just my feeling.

Comment: @computerfreaker, that's not a bad starting point.  It's not a perfect fit, unfortunately, because it doesn't handle groups of bits.  Nevertheless, it's still a reasonable starting place.

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be:

- do not mess up the structure definitions
- find all places where data is loaded or saved (or received or send)
- add on this places a conversion to a defined byteorder (for convinience use the byteorder of your past target
- for this conversions create functions that are implemented hardware dependent or even better use htonX and ntohX routines to convert data to and from network byteorder (that is afaik BigEndian)